# How to generate calendar?

Tags: django, django-templates

How to generate calendar based on datetime viariable view in template like this?

```
<< Jan               Mar >>
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
          1   2   3   4   5
  6   7   8   9  10  11  12
 13  14  15  16  17  18  19
 20  21  22  23  24  25  26
 27  28  29  30  31
```

in tables/div whatever...

Comment: No,things that I found are support events. I have own event system, I just want to draw a calendar based on date. Version alpha is here: https://github.com/MobyDevel/django-portal

Comment: Have a look at [django-gencal](https://github.com/justinlilly/django-gencal)

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by "datetime variable view". HTML5 has a tag for this. http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_input_types.asp (Does NOT work with Firefox yet) OR you may use one of the *many* JS datepickers available. One of them: http://javascriptcalendar.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[simple django event calendar](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2464/)

Answer (score 0):

You might find the stdlib module `calendar` helpful:

```
>>> calendar.monthcalendar(2011, 9)
[[ 0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4], 
 [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11], 
 [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], 
 [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25], 
 [26, 27, 28, 29, 30,  0,  0]]
```

(with whitespace added to show structure)